# Displaybug in Magento backend calendar

Tags: magento-1.7, css

The calendar in magento backend double his width when I hover over the hour or minute field.

An image show what I mean:

[image: (left how it is when I] hover, right the normal version)

Language: german (de_DE)

I have this in different installations. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Most probably is's because of the text appearing below "Drucken Sie...", It's kind of long. Try to change the text or make the element that contains is have a fixed width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably is's because of the text appearing below "Drucken Sie...", It's kind of long. Try to change the text or make the element that contains is have a fixed width.

---

<sub>Initially a comment. Posted as an answer at the request of the OP</sub>